# Query dynamoDB with key condition 'GE' on a hash key

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to run a query on a dynamoDB table with the key condition as such

```
KeyConditions: {
  userID: {
    ComparisonOperator: 'GE',
    AttributeValueList: [{N: '0'}]
  }
}
```

When I run this query with the ComparisonOperator as 'EQ' no problems occur. However when it's 'GE' I get an error stating that the query key condition is not supported.

Note that userID is a hash key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Dynamo DB Query Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html):

> A Query operation directly accesses items from a table using the table primary key, or from an index using the index key. You must provide a specific hash key value. You can narrow the scope of the query by using comparison operators on the range key value, or on the index key. You can use the ScanIndexForward parameter to get results in forward or reverse order, by range key or by index key.

You must provide a hash key to query Dynamo DB.  You could accomplish what you're trying to do with a `Scan` operation or with multiple `Query` operations, but there's no way to specify a condition other than equals for a hash key in DynamoDB.