# Attempted conditional constraint is not an indexable operation issue in dynamodb

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

In DynamoDB my query is not working with ComparisonOperator other than `EQ` in PHP. I am using Global Secondary Indexes:

```
$response = $client->query(array(
    "TableName" => $tableName,
    "IndexName" => "topRating", // GSI index name
    "KeyConditions" => array(
        "rating" => array(
            "ComparisonOperator" => "NE", // Only 'EQ' works
            "AttributeValueList" => array(
                array(Type::STRING => "1186") // Sample value
            )
        )
    ),
    "ScanIndexForward" => true,
    "limit" => 5
));
```

When creating the table I used `rating` as hash key for creating `topRating` GSI

The response is as follows:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\ValidationException: AWS 
>   Error Code: ValidationException, Status Code: 400, AWS Request ID: 
>   XXXXXYYYYYZZZZ, AWS Error Type:  client, AWS Error Message: Attempted
>   conditional constraint is not an  indexable operation, User-Agent:
>   aws-sdk-php2/2.7.0 Guzzle/3.9.2  curl/7.19.7 PHP/5.4.30 thrown in ....

Comment: What is the response?

Comment: Please edit your question and paste that output between [code tags](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Also maybe remove or feign sensitive/revealing information like personal folder names and request id's

Answer (score 0):

According to the AWS docs ([link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonDynamoDB/query)), it seems that the `query` operation doesn't support the  `NE` operator:

> Scan operations support all available comparison operators. Query operations support a subset of the available comparison operators: EQ, LE, LT, GE, GT, BETWEEN, and BEGINS_WITH.

The [`scan`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonDynamoDB/scan) operation does support it.

Comment: Does aws query support any other ComparisonOperator except EQ? Actually when I am using LE it shows 'Query key condition not supported'.

Comment: Which SDK version are you using? My answer apparently applied to an older version. In the docs of version 2.7.2 ([link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.DynamoDb_2011_12_05.DynamoDbClient.html)) it says that the `NE` operator _is_ supported (Search the webpage for _ComparisonOperator_).

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696538/query-dynamodb-with-key-condition-ge-on-a-hash-key) says: "There's no way to specify a condition other than equals for a hash key in DynamoDB."